# How to wipe an old white MacBook?

Tags: install

Reading over Apple's documents on how to wipe a machine, it's all about internet installs. Now it's been so long since I did anything with this machine, I don't recall the process... was 10.7.5 an internet-based install?

What options do I have to wipe an old white MacBook?

Comment: Without knowing the exact model information, I'd suggest your start by reading [What to do before selling or giving away your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201065) and go from there.

Comment: Does the Mac run? Do you have another Mac to connect it to? Lots of ways to help, but we don't know how far you are or what tidbit is needed to explain how to move you a step closer to your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is...

Using OS X boot media or your recovery partition (if available; <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), boot into it like you are going to do an install.  However, when you get to the first screen, launch Disk Utility and do a "Secure Erase" of your hard drive.

Once that is done, you can stop there and have a white MB with no OS or you can continue and install an OS for the next person who becomes the new owner.

**Can your white MB support Internet Recovery?**

If it is the 2010 model (their last one before resurrecting the line last year) and you had Lion installed with the EFI Firmware update, you can use Internet Recovery.  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202313

There's no harm in checking...just press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> during boot.  If you get to Internet Recovery, then you have it.  If not, then chances are, your MB doesn't support it.

Comment: If Internet Recovery is not supported, the OP could just use the internal Recovery partition to reinstall OS X. As an alternative.

Comment: @aidanb.01  That's true.  I updated my answer to reflect that fact.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I create a USB drive with 10.7 or 10.8 on it and then plug it in, restart the computer and hold the "C" key, which will let you choose to boot it from the USB. After that, just use disk utility to wipe the HD and then install the OS.

http://www.macworld.com/article/1161069/software-system/make-a-bootable-lion-installer.html

http://www.macworld.com/article/1167857/software-system/how-to-make-a-bootable-mountain-lion-install-drive.html

Those are some resources I've used to create bootable drives!