# Erase MacBook hard drive without the use of the mouse

Tags: hard-drive, mouse

I want to sell my Early 2015 MacBook Pro Retina.

It has an unknown issue where the mouse input isn't working properly and I can't click (when using either the trackpad or a USB mouse).

I have got to the Disk Utility page but I can't click the 'Erase' button to finish the job and there seems to be no way to do this with the keyboard.

Is there a way I can erase the hard drive without using the mouse? I can access the Terminal when I login.

Comment: What software are you on? You can probably use voice control if it’s recent enough.

Comment: Are you selling it *because* of this USB issue or is it just a coincidence?  Have you booting into Safe Mode (hold shift while booting) to see if there's a driver/kext issue?  Did you try booting into [Recovery Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) hold `⌘-R ` while booting.  You can erase the disk from here via Terminal and also diagnose the mouse issue.  Is it still happening?

Comment: If you can reboot into recovery, you can erase the drive with the instructions here:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/228861/119271

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Keyboard combination to erase your Macbook with VoiceOver's accessibility feature.

1. First, reboot your computer and be in Recovery mode with the combination of <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
2. At the recovery welcome screen, press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> keys (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, if you're on an Apple laptop) to enable VoiceOver's accessibility features.
3. On the macOS Utilities selection screen, use the arrow keys to highlight Disk Utility, press the Tab button to highlight the Continue button and press <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> as instructed by the voice-over display screen.
4. Use <kbd>⇥</kbd> (tab) if needed to be on your Macintosh HD-Data. Once you follow the voice control option, you can be on Erase option, and press <kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
5. Voila !! it is done without any mouse too.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done from **macOS Recovery** without the use of a **mouse** and primarily using just the **arrow**, **tab** and **space** *keys*. The **enter** *key* may need to be used on some *objects*, depending on the selection(s) made:

1. Boot to **macOS Recovery** by holding down **⌘R** when starting the Mac.
2. At the **macOS Utilities** window, press the **down-arrow** *key* four times. This highlights **Disk Utility** because the table containing it already has focus when booted to **macOS Recovery**.
3. Press the **tab** *key* once to highlight the **Continue** *button*.
4. Press the **space** *key* to actuate the highlighted **Continue** *button*, which starts **Disk Utility**.

In **Disk Utility**:

1. Use the **up-arrow** *key* to highlight the e.g. **Macintosh HD**, or whichever **volume** you want to erase.
2. Use the **tab** *key* multiple times until the **Erase** *button* on the **Toolbar** is highlighted.
3. Press the **space** *key* to actuate the highlighted **Erase** *button*.
4. On the ensuing **sheet**, e.g. **Erase Macintosh HD**, use the previously mentioned *keystroke* methods to *navigate*, *select* and *actuate* the *buttons* as wanted. You can also actuate the **Format:** pop-up menu, once selected with the **tab** *key*, with the **up-arrow** or **down-arrow** *keys* and press the **enter** *key* after making the selection.

<sub>**Note:** These steps were tested from **macOS Recovery** on a system running **macOS Catalina** and works as described without the use of **VoiceOver**.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers provided, if at any point you want to access the menus in the menu bar using only the keyboard, you can use `control (⌃)` + `F2` to move your focus to the menu bar, then use your arrow keys to navigate the menus.

For example, this would allow you to access the `Edit` > `Erase...` option within the Disk Utility menus.

Additionally, this would allow you to access the Terminal by selecting `Utilities` > `Terminal` in the macOS Recovery menus.

From Terminal, you could run `diskutil` commands to erase the internal disk.

`diskutil list` will list all the disks the system is aware of. If your goal is to erase the internal disk, there is a good chance that will be listed as `/dev/disk0 (internal)`.

Here is a sample from my MacBook Pro that shipped with a 512GB drive.

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         500.3 GB   disk0
   1:             Apple_APFS_ISC ⁨⁩                        524.3 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk3⁩         494.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:        Apple_APFS_Recovery ⁨⁩                        5.4 GB     disk0s3
```

You can then run the `diskutil eraseDisk` command to erase the internal disk using the HFS+ format, and labeling it as the default "Macintosh HD".

```
diskutil eraseDisk HFS+J "Macintosh HD" /dev/disk0
```

The disk will then be fully erased and ready for a clean installation of macOS.

Answer (score -3):

If you can open the Terminal, the command `rm -r *` will erase the whole disk, we usually avoid telling anyone that because they may accidentally use it - most people here aren't looking to erase their disk drive.  You can type `man rm` to read the man page for the `rm` command.

Comment: Very few systems will let you erase the whole disk with rm -rf these days, unless it's targeting an external disk. MacOS certainly won't let you since SIP was introduced, and most other enterprise-class OSes (e.g. Solaris) have similar protections.